# `$(window).on('load', function() {...}` doesn't work on link follow or back click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function preloader() {
    console.log('here')
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden').css('padding', '');
            });
        }, 100);
    }

}

$(window).on('load', preloader);
```

This works when page is opened on new tab in browser or after page refresh, however, it doesn't work when page is loaded after following usual link or hitting back button.

`here` is displayed in console only after refresh

Comment: Do you specifically need to catch the `load` event? If not, I’d suggest you use jQuery’s default [ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/): `$(function() { ... })`

Comment: @MTCoster thanks I tried document ready and when it didn't work it made me look in right direction

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is turned out to be Ruby on Rails gem `turbolink` specific, which changes body content without page reload under the hood.

It emits special event on which you can track it reloaded page:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
...
})
```